# send long press keyevent programmatically

Tags: android

For my testing application, I need to send long press keyevents. For which I am using the below code.

```
Instrumentation mInstrumentation = new Instrumentation();
KeyEvent k = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyEvent);
mInstrumentation.sendKeySync(k);
try {
    Thread.sleep(KEYEVENT_INTERVAL);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}

for (int repetition = 0; repetition < times; repetition++) {
    KeyEvent newEvent = KeyEvent.changeTimeRepeat(k, SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 1,
                                          k.getFlags() | KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS);
    mInstrumentation.sendKeySync(newEvent);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(KEYEVENT_INTERVAL);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

mInstrumentation.sendKeySync(
    new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyEvent));
```

But this provides the same result as

```
for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
mInstrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(keyEvent);
SystemClock.sleep(KEYEVENT_INTERVAL);
}
```

What is the difference between the above solutions?

If the above solutions for long press were wrong, then How can I send long press key Events programmatically?